# C - Makefile error

Tags: c, makefile

I am just starting out with C and now I am at the part where I want to learn about Makefiles.  I am starting out small but already failing ;)

I have a very simple Makefile which just compiles the main.c to a main.o and then to an executable. But I get an error saying I have a syntax error.  I use `g++`.

The command that i use are:

```
g++ make Makefile << name of the make file
```

And the Makefile is set up like this:

```
main.o: main.c main.h
[TAB]   g++ -c main.c

main: main.o
[TAB]   g++ main.o -o main
```

Comment: If you're using C, you should use gcc instead of g++ (but it's still wrong for a makefile).

Comment: I am on windows, i thought g++ is the windows version of gcc. I got it from MinGW

Comment: No, both gcc (C Compiler) e g++ (C++ compiler) are part of GCC (GNU Compiler Collection), and they are both in the MinGW porting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run make on the Makefile (the default name), invoke the make command:

```
$ make
```

Don't try to call g++ with the makefile, the compiler knows nothing about makefiles.

**EDIT**: You say you don't have the make command, in a comment. Then you need to get it. :) There are several versions of make for Windows, [here is GNU make](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) (which is common in Linux and other Unix-like environments) ported to Windows.

Comment: I am a novic in all of does commands, but my windows doesn't have ( probaly i am not doing it correct ) command make?